# MediaRecorder fails on start on some devices (start failed: -2147483648 and -19)

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder, video-recording

I have read everything about [MediaRecorder and followed the GUIDES on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video).

Well, it supose to work fine at least on API 8 and higher, but my minimum SDK is 14, so I it should be better.

On my device, Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini it works fine. Some other devices with Ice Cream Sandwitch as well, **but some others not**. They crash on:

```
mediaRecorder.start()
```

I create a service for recording video and this is my code (guide for what I do on every stage):

```
    @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    //OPEN CAMERA
    int ncamara=0;
    qcamara=0;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<9)
        camera = Camera.open();                                       
    else{
    try {
        ncamara = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if (f.leer("camara", context).equals("frontal"))
            qcamara=10;
        else qcamara=20;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    if (ncamara>=2 && qcamara == 10)
        camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
    else if (ncamara>=2 && qcamara == 20)
        camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
    else
        camera = Camera.open();
    }
                                                                        //
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    //UNLOCK CAMERA
    camera.unlock();    
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);                                    //setCamera
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

                                                                        //setProfile
    if (f.leer("calidad", context).equals("alta") && qcamara !=10)
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(0, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    else if (f.leer("calidad", context).equals("alta") && qcamara == 10)
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(1, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    else if (f.leer("calidad", context).equals("baja") && qcamara != 10)
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(0, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    else
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(1, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);   

    if (CameraRecorder.duracion>0)                                      // -- duration
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(CameraRecorder.duracion * 1000);


    File dataDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File fileDir = new File(dataDirectory, "/weddingR/");
    fileDir.mkdirs();
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(                                        //setOutputFile
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/weddingR/"+
            DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd---kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime())+
            ".mp4"
    );
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());  
    if (qcamara==10){ // FRONT CAMERA
        try { mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270); } catch (Exception e) {}
    } else { // BACK CAMERA
        try { mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    try { 
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener(){

        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d("INFO_ON", what + " " + extra + " ");
            nascosto=true;
            stopSelf();
        }
    });

    mediaRecorder.start();
}
```

If I set `mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20)` for example, it crashes on every device.

I'm most asking before in some devices works fine, but not others (for example, EMULATOR with API 17 or 18 works... devices with API 15 works but EMULATOR API 15 doesn't work...)

What am I doing wrong ??

Thanks in advance.

---

**ANDROID MANIFEST PERMISSIONS**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

---

**EDIT**

After @Melquiades answer, I edited my code now catching exceptions and no exception is caught.

Also, I'd like to point some interesting thing: I'm trying with API15 emulator and this happens:

1. When I set `mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());` (after `mediaRecorder.setOutputFile()`), I get `START FAILED -19`
2. When I don't set it, I get `START FAILED -2147483648`

But in my Samsung it still works fine...

---

**NEW EDIT** (01/01/2014) HAPPY NEW YEAR!!

I tried on Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus (Android 4.1.2) and it doesn't work, but on mine, Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini it works (also Android 4.1.2)... I'm becoming crazy.

Comment: you should unlock camera before doing  camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();

Comment: After your answer, I read some on StackOverflow and it's reccomended to set the `camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);` and `camera.startPreview();` when calling `surfaceChanged()` .

I did that but still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

When calling mediaRecorder.prepare(), you're not doing anything with caught exception:

```
try { 
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) { //empty??? }
```

DON'T DO IT. It's a bad practice. If there are any exceptions, you won't know it.

Place a Log.d() inside {} and see what's going on during prepare(). Do it with all your exceptions that you're catching.

From that guide:

```
// Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
try {
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

I don't use to do that bad practice, but thanks for reminding me. I'm catching the exceptions and I have no exceptions. It just crashes. I'm editing my EDIT so you can know what happens if I modify some parameters.